# How to calculate I_D and V_GS in a JFET with load resistance

Tags: amplifier, jfet

[image]

When \$V_\text{DS} = V_\text{P}\$, thus \$I_\text{D}\$ will achieve maximum value hence equal to \$I_\text{DSS}=10\text{mA}\$. By substituting \$I_D\$ into \$I_\text{D}=I_\text{DSS}\left(1-V_\text{GS}/V_\text{P}\right)^2\$, I got \$V_\text{GS} = 0V\$. However by doing this way I'm ignoring the effect of load resistance and it's a 10 marks question I don't think it is this simple.

I have also try to use \$I_D\$ into \$I_\text{D}=I_\text{DSS}\left(1-V_\text{GS}/V_\text{P}\right)^2\$ to approach the question but there are two unknowns \$I_D\$ and \$V_\text{GS}\$ and I'm stuck. There are others information provided such as load resistance, \$V_\text{DD}\$ and \$V_\text{GG}\$ which I have try to relate them using following formula (Correct me if I'm wrong) :
$$
\begin{align}
 V_\text{DS} &= V_\text{DD} - I_D \cdot R_D\\
V_\text{GS} &= V_\text{GG} - I_G \cdot R_G
\end{align}
$$
However, I cannot find a way to relate them to \$I_\text{D}=I_\text{DSS}\left(1-V_\text{GS}/V_\text{P}\right)^2\$ to solve it.

Comment: Do you wan to have Vds = 4V? Yes?

Comment: V_ds given in the question is equal to V_p so it should be -5.0V too

Comment: I think that you are wrongly interpreting the question.  In your circuit, you cannot have negative Vds. It is simply impossible.

Comment: I'm actually new to this so I thought that would be the case.  If only the magnitude is equal it makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**. I am assuming that \$V_\text{DS}=\lvert V_\text{P}\rvert\$ since only in this case the condition \$V_\text{GS} -V_\text{DS} \le V_\text{P}\$ under which the fundamental formula for \$ I_\text{D} \$ is applicable surely holds. Despite this, we'll see that there are some incongruences from the point of view of the schematics shown in the OP: precisely, the gate circuit cannot be the one shown.

Let's start by considering the anode mesh: by applying the Kelvin Voltage Law (KVL for short) we have
$$
V_\text{DD}-R_\text{D}I_\text{D}-V_\text{DS}=0
$$
Since \$V_\text{DS}=5\text{V}\$ and \$V_\text{DD}=16\text{V}\$ are known you have that
$$
R_\text{D}I_\text{D}=V_\text{DD}-V_\text{DS}\iff I_\text{D}=\frac{V_\text{DD}-V_\text{DS}}{R_\text{D}}=\frac{16\text{V}-5\text{V}}{10\text{k}\Omega}=1.1\text{mA}
$$
Now you can use the fundamental \$I_\text{D} = f(V_\text{GS})\$ by plugging in it the found value of \$I_\text{D}\$
$$
\begin{split}
I_\text{D} = I_\text{DSS}\left(1-\frac{V_\text{GS}}{V_\text{P}}\right)^2 &\iff \sqrt{\frac{I_\text{D}}{I_\text{DSS}}} = \left(1-\frac{V_\text{GS}}{V_\text{P}}\right)\\
&\iff {V_\text{GS}}= V_\text{P}\left(1 - \sqrt{\frac{I_\text{D}}{I_\text{DSS}}}\right)\\
& \iff
{V_\text{GS}}= (-5\text{V})\left(1 - \sqrt{\frac{1.1\text{mA}}{10\text{mA}}}\right) \\
&\iff {V_\text{GS}}= (-5\text{V})\left(1 - \sqrt{{0.11}}\right)\\
&\iff V_\text{GS} \simeq -3,34\text{V}
\end{split}
$$
**Notes**

The result found is in contrast with the circuit in that in the schematics is shown a \$V_\text{GG}\$ voltage of \$-1\text{V}\$ (respect to the source): this clearly cannot be as by applying the KVL law to the input circuit the have that
$$
V_\text{GG}-R_\text{G}I_\text{G}-V_\text{GS}=0 \iff V_\text{GG} \le V_\text{GS}\iff V_\text{GG} \le -3,34\text{V}.
$$
Possibly, the text of the exercise was added to a picture draw for another one, and this caused a bit of confusion.